# Inequality $(a+b+c)^5\ge 81(a^2+b^2+c^2)abc$ with $a,b,c\in{}\mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Prove that for every positive real numbers $a,b$ and $c$ we have

$$(a+b+c)^5\ge 81(a^2+b^2+c^2)abc.$$

I tried using the u,v,w method by substituting

$$a+b+c=3u$$
$$ab+bc+ca=3v^2$$
$$abc=w^3$$

From which it suffices to show $u^5-3u^2w^3+2v^2w^3\geq0$. Im quite stuck here and unable to proceed. Also I know that equality occurs when $a=b=c$.

Comment: For $u,v,w$ you may note the function is linear in $w^3$, so will achieve extrema when $w^3$ takes extreme values. As $u\ge v$, we need the max of $w^3$. For positives, this means you will need to check when all $a=b=c$.  Of course this problem is better done using AM-GM or CS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I tried adding vvnitram's condition, but it doesn't sit well with me, because from cauchy-scharwz $(1 + 1 + 1)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \geq (a + b + c)^2$

This inequality should only work for non negative numbers. From AM-GM
\begin{align}
\frac{a + b + c}{3} &\geq (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
(a + b + c)^3 &\geq 27abc
\end{align}
Now for positive numbers  $a$, $b$ and $c$ it follows that
\begin{align}
(a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc \geq a^2 + b^2 + c^2
\end{align}
Using vvnitram's condition, assuming $a \geq b \geq c$ then 
\begin{equation}
(a + b + c)^2 \geq 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
\end{equation}
(because $ab > b^2$)
If $a \geq b$ and $c \geq d$ for positive numbers then $ac \geq bd$. So using the above two inequalities
\begin{align}
(a + b + c)^3 \cdot (a + b + c)^2 &\geq 27abc \cdot 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)\\
(a + b + c)^5 &\geq 81abc(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
\end{align}

Comment: you made mistake in the second line. it should be $(a + b + c)^3 \geq 27abc
$

Comment: @Jeevan Devaranjan The inequality in the seventh line is wrong. Try $b=c\rightarrow0^+$ and $a=1$.

Answer (score 6):

Assume the variables are positive. By homogeneity we may assume that $a+b+c=1$. Maximize $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(abc)$ subject to $a+b+c=1$ using Lagrange multipliers. The calculation is unusually simple, for we get $3a^2bc=3b^2ac=3c^2ab=\lambda$. Of course this is not in the spirit of the inequalities game.

Answer (score 1):

Set
\begin{aligned}
P = (a+b+c)^5 - 81abc(a^2+b^2+c^2).
\end{aligned}
We have
\begin{aligned}
P = \frac12 \sum\left[b^3+21c^3+ab(4a+b)+(10c+a)(a-b)^2\right](a-b)^2
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

By using your substitutions we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0$, where $f$ is a decreasing function.

Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^3$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume $y=z=1$, which gives
$$(x-1)^2(x^3+12x^2-18x+32)\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Positives? If one is 0 and others negatives is false.

Assume that are positives and then:

i) $(\frac{a+b+c}{3})^3\geq abc$ by am-gm
ii) $(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \iff ab+bc+ac\geq a^2+b^2+c^2$ that is true because assuming $a\geq b \geq c$ then $ab\geq b^2$ and the cycle.

Because all is positive, the product of inequalities is the problem.

Comment: Why don't you try the cycle out and see what happens?  For future reference, $3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge (a+b+c)^2$ and also $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ca$ - both can be proved using any number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

By AM-GM we obtain:
$$(a+b+c)^5=\frac{((a+b+c)^2)^3}{a+b+c}=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+2ab)\right)^3}{a+b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(3\sqrt[3]{\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\right)^2}\right)^3}{a+b+c}=\frac{27(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+ac+bc)^2}{a+b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{27(a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot3(a+b+c)abc}{a+b+c}=81(a^2+b^2+c^2)abc.$$